# How to use DCMTK classes in javascript

Tags: node.js, class, native-code, dcmtk

I know how to use findscu, echoscu etc from a shell program and also grabbing output from a shell in program codes, i.e. using node.js child_process spawn, etc. But in the official site, there are also classes available, i.e. [DcmDateTime](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs-snapshot/classDcmDateTime.html), etc. How can I use those in my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is what you want, but it seems to be possible to cross-compile the DCMTK for use in a JavaScript environment. E.g. for [dcmjs](https://github.com/commontk/dcmjs) this was done with [emscripten](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/).